# In Appurchase Using promocode in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Here I am developing the iOS App, regarding the purchasing plans by using the InApp Purchase(IAP). As per the Apple document by using Consumable, Non-Consumable and Subscriptions Implemented the IAP depends upon the requirements

In addition they have a requirement to buy the plan from using the Promocodes, According to this I referred the Apple docs in this link "Requesting Promo Codes"

But I didnt get any idea wheather its possible (or) Not. Please help for this IAP Promocode details

Comment: those promo-codes are not available for iAP. _"Promo codes don't work for In-App Purchase products, including Newsstand issues."_ (source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, As per your instruction The Promocode will not used in IAP. Given doc supports only regarding to purchasing the Application, I am right?

Comment: yes, that is the case exactly.